# STA MVC application doesnt end long running requests

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, com

I need to run my ASP.NET MVC application in STA mode. For this purpose I developed some custom classes based on [Programming ASP.NET MVC 4: Developing Real-World Web Applications with ASP.NET MVC](https://books.google.cz/books?id=0jyfL7CzXvgC&pg=PA314&lpg=PA314&dq=%22this.AspCompatEndProcessRequest(result);%22&source=bl&ots=bo0ci2m25G&sig=4hmAR_RizZd7vbpXYtnMbvsD6Uo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjGjISF_Z_XAhXD-6QKHf4KDu4Q6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=%22this.AspCompatEndProcessRequest(result)%3B%22&f=false). Here they are:

```
public class StaThreadRouteHandler : IRouteHandler
{
    public IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        if (requestContext == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("requestContext");

        return new StaThreadHttpAsyncHandler(requestContext);
    }
}

public class StaThreadHttpAsyncHandler : Page, IHttpAsyncHandler, IRequiresSessionState
{
    private readonly RequestContext _requestContext;
    public StaThreadHttpAsyncHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        if (requestContext == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("requestContext");

        _requestContext = requestContext;
    }

    public IAsyncResult BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, object extraData)
    {
        return this.AspCompatBeginProcessRequest(context, cb, extraData);
    }

    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        var controllerName = _requestContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("controller");
        var controllerFactory = ControllerBuilder.Current.GetControllerFactory();
        var controller = controllerFactory.CreateController(_requestContext, controllerName);
        if (controller == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Could not find controller: " + controllerName);
        try
        {
            controller.Execute(_requestContext);
        }
        finally
        {
            controllerFactory.ReleaseController(controller);
        }
        this.Context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
    }

    public void EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        this.AspCompatEndProcessRequest(result);
    }

    public override void ProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException("STAThreadRouteHandler does not support ProcessRequest called (only BeginProcessRequest)");
    }
}
```

Also adjusted RouteConfig:

```
routes.Add(new Route("{controller}/{action}/{id}", new StaThreadRouteHandler ()))
```

Everything works fine for majority of my actions, but I have two that take somewhere between 10 and 20 seconds to finish. For these two actions, method `EndProcessRequest` is never executed, even though no exception is thrown during their execution and `this.Context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();` is called within `OnInit` without problems. As a result, such request ends in IIS with state `ExecuteRequestHandler` and is stuck there forever and also blocks new requests from being served.
[image]

Why is this happening? Why breakpoint in `EndProcessRequest` is never hit for long running actions, while it works fine for shorter actions (1-5 seconds).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was not related to execution time of particular actions at all. Not really sure what was happening under hood but all the problematic actions had one in common - they were creating one particular COM object, which I guess was somehow not properly destroyed and as a result `EndProcessRequest` was not called.

The issue was happening for any .NET COM object, native COM objects are fine and `EndProcessRequest` is called.